# getstream.io - Cannot create user in PHP backend

Tags: php, react-native, getstream-io

I have created a React Native app with a stream from react-native-activity-feed. I use PHP as backend to generate the user session token;

```
$userId = "42";    
$userToken = client->createUserSessionToken($userId);
```

In my emulator I get following error:

> TypeError: user_id is missing in user token.

This may be because I don't have any users yet on my app. When I try adding a user in my PHP backend using following code I get following error

```
$user = $client->users()->add('42', array('name' => 'Arthur Dent'));
```

> Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException: Server error: `POST
>   https://api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/user/` resulted in a `502 Bad
>   Gateway`

How do I create a user?

Comment: are you 100% sure that the token used in JS is the same as the one generated by PHP? just to be sure can you console.log the token (JS side) and post it here (you can skip the 3rd section so that it won't contain the signature)

Comment: were you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: I made it work by creating a different production app in getstream located in a different region.